# Identify duplicate tiles

Tags: java, image, hash, bufferedimage, tile

I have one `BufferedImage` with multiple tiles in it.

What I want is to compare the tiles against each other to see if they are identical.

So how do I extract the data out of each individual tile from the buffered image that can be used in the hash algorithm to compare them?

Comment: What have you tried? [Read this please](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Hashes _might_ collide.  You're going to need to compare the actual contents.  Which will probably mean that you need to actually construct the tile one-at-a-time, then compare all incoming constructions to see if one is already using that data.  What have you got so far?

Comment: I do not agree with that article.

When I came to this site I came to search for knowledge I don't have.I did not came here for trial and error.I do not know the functionality of the hash functions or data they use so that is what I want to know.

Comment: according to your last comment, then here is what you want: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Comment: I know what I want,what I don't have is the method to extract the tile data in java and how to use a hash function in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) for this. quoting from the page:

> This MessageDigest class provides applications the functionality of a
>   message digest algorithm, such as SHA-1 or SHA-256. Message digests
>   are secure one-way hash functions that take arbitrary-sized data and
>   output a fixed-length hash value.

you can search for examples of using this class to see how to implement hashing with different hashing algorithms. you can also use other libraries which simplifies the work for you, like [DigestUtils](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) from apache commons. for our case, i will use the example from the page above:

first, get the data for a tile: we go over the pixels that make the tile and read the rgb value. that will be an int. Noticing the API for message digest, you need to make it a byte array and update the digest. You can either make a method that gets a byte array from an int. or you can concatenate the ints into a string and get a full array for the whole string that represent all the ints in a tile. then you get the bytes from that String. Note i will be using hardcoded values just for demonstration on the first tile and that i will not deal with exceptions etc ... :

```
StringBuilder firstImageRGBStr=new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<32; i++)
 for (int j=0; j<32; j++)
   firstImageRGBStr.append(img.getRGB(i,j));


MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
byte[] firstImageDigest = md.digest(firstImageRGBStr.toString().getBytes());
```

now you store the byte array as the hash of your first tile for future comparisons.
Note you don't need to create a new MessageDigest for every tile as after saving the hash of a tile, you can use [reset()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#reset%28%29) to reuse the message digest for another tile.

to compare hashes now becomes a comparison of the byte arrays that contain the hash. and note that the class MessageDigest has a static method that compares two digests which just does that [isEqual()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html#isEqual%28byte%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D%29).

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to compare hashes, it's easy enough to just go through the images pixel by pixel.

```
  assert imageA.getWidth() == imageB.getWidth();
  assert imageA.getHeight() == imageB.getHeight();

  for (int x = 0; x < imageA.getWidth(); x++)
  {
     for (int y = 0; y < imageA.getHeight(); y++)
     {
        assert imageA.getRGB(x, y) == imageB.getRGB(x, y);
     }
  }
```

Comment: In a 1024 buffer that would be 1 million checks which I doubt is fast.

Although I don't know how fast the hash is.

Comment: @adrix89 I've implemented this before, it's plenty fast. If you implemented a hash you would still need to read the whole image.

Comment: Wait your actually wrong since we are checking every tile against every tile. [32x32(a tile)*1023](check for one tile)*1024(to check for ever tile against every tiles).That's 1,072,693,248 image.getRGP(x,y) in the worst case scenario when we have all uniques so not fancy optimizations possible.

Comment: @adrix89 are you trying to search the first image for any tiles that exist anywhere in the second image? You need to reword your question to be more clear.

Comment: There is only one image,there are multiple tiles withing the buffer image that needs to be compared against each other.